# DataTables: Automatic width on start-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables for jQuery (https://datatables.net/) to create a table. I am using JavaScript to populate the table. When it is initially created, the columnn with has some adjustment (some columns are wider than others), but it is not perfect, for example there is a two line row as in the first picture below. After resizing and maximizing again, the table is readjusted to the optimal state, with plenty of room for the row with a long name. How to I get this adjustment directly after I load the table?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can set the width in th  `<th width="350px">`

Comment: try sWidth in column definitions. Like "sWidth": "20%" or "sWidth": "20px".   For reference see: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `columns.adjust()` [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) you can see how.

Comment: @Mattias this is from datatables version 1.10 and greater. Work according your version of datatables